# Picking rows with list of keywords

Tags: python, file

I have two files like below. From File 1 and File 2, I need to create a dictionary.

#### File 1

```
procedure            code
anand database      321-87
Guy shiva network   321-123
jana audit          321-56
```

#### File 2

```
kalai has a recruitment group
shiva is the network guy in my office
he is the auditor in my audit office
anand is the database here
i bought a new phone and 1 kg of apple
```

#### Requirement

I need to pick rows from File 2 which contains all the keywords of each row in File 2 (`procedure` column) and if a row in File 2 has all the keywords, then map it to the code of that concern keywords with that picked procedure.

#### Expected output

```
S.No      procedure                          code
1    shiva is the network guy in my office  321-123
2    anand is the database here             321-87
3    i bought a red color apple             321-10
```

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Have you tried something? What exactly are you having problems with?